# Application that depends on Disk Swap can only load on 1st try after Fresh Boot

Tags: linux, debian, swap

(original text redacted, too much clutter, bad grammar, replaced by summary below)

**Screenshots** with more detail here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xfZq.jpg

Main symptom: Game that depends on disk Swap can only finish loading fast **the 1st time after a fresh boot** (2 Gigs of Swap use is populated in less than 40 seconds, normal write speed)

Secondary symptom: On any successive tries to load the game again, 2nd time, 3rd time, etc, **the game will only be able to finish loading AFTER Swap is already populated** with an average disk write speed of not more than 2 MB/s (load time will jump from 90 seconds to up to 7 minutes, if Swap was empty it will lead to a crash)

3rd Symptom: after Swap is populated (normal daily usage over time) you can verify the amount of time it takes to Empty/Flush the Swapfile using the Swapoff command and monitoring it in real-time with a terminal window running watch -n 1 free -h... In my case, the Swap will flush very slowly at an average rate of 2 MB/s (again indicating that something is interfering with I/O functionality on linux... **Disk swap is slow, while Zram swap remains fast, being flushed in less than 3 seconds**, monitor in real-time)

UPDATE 2: (after a year)
After updating distros, new round of tests, etc, I've made another discovery: if I try to quit the game and load it a 2nd time, a 3rd time, etc, then disk swapping becomes very slow, disk can't keep up with the CPU demands, and the game can't finish loading (or it does finish loading taking 7 times the normal time)
Now this is the surprising part: **if I Logout of my desktop and Login once again**, the game loads fast once again, like if I had rebooted my computer. SOMETHING is interfering with Disk I/O, but I'm not sure what exactly.

**"SOLUTION" / Temporary Workaround:**
Logout and Login back again into the desktop (in some distros, you might need to use the command sudo killall -u username in TTY)
That seems to "reset" the disk Write Speed and Swap access speed in general (any ideas why???)

Comment: Hi folks. Please don't have long discussions in comments. I have now [moved your discussion to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124486/discussion-on-question-by-winampah-why-is-disk-swapping-faster-in-manjaro-than-d).

Comment: There's a ton of info which will take a considerable amount of time to get familiarized with. If I were you, I'd just add more RAM if possible. It's quite weird your have issues with RAM/disk speeds, yet you haven't provided any info for the matter, `free` and`top` output while running the game, `uname -a`, etc. etc. etc. It makes trying to guess what's going on really difficult.

Comment: Also check https://www.thegeekdiary.com/using-vmstat-to-troubleshoot-performance-issues-in-linux/ https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/linux-commands-vmstat

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov I'm not a Linux beginner, but thanks for your taking time to writing here. That's exactly my point. This game (Cities Skylines) presents me with an opportunity to get the system into an "stressful" status really quick. The symptons mentioned in this question are not the usual usage of the system, this is a pretty peculiar situation. Others also report this kind of "system panic" when having MySQL servers, Java applications (although Java has a built-in Heap Size Limitation feature) I understand all this. What I'm trying to figure out here is: why disk gets slow when CPU high?

Comment: (character limit, please have in mind) @ArtemS.Tashkinov That's why I'm asking for the help of experts in this I/O subject like you, Artem. I feel like I've already figured out 90% of the puzzle, the hardest part is already done. I'm getting so close, can't just give up now. My most recent update: changing /proc/sys/vm values do NOTHING in terms of performance under heavy load, system still freezes. In Manjaro, this does not occur, only in Debian. This is not exclusive to Cities Skylines either, Unity games like Kerbal Space Program for example will have these disk-swapping issues. C#/DotNet

Comment: You're running different kernels, compiled differently, you're low on RAM - I'm not sure what is that you're trying to achieve. Get some voodoo knowledge of the kernel? ;-) Why would you waste so much time though?

Comment: Over time, updating distros and performing more tests, I found out another piece of this puzzle: the game (which requires heavy disk Swapping to load up) works fine out of a fresh boot (the 1st load is always the fastest one) It works normally the 1st time, right after boot (which lead me to the false belief that Manjaro was not affected... turns out it happens on Manjaro too)

Comment: I also made another discovery: if I try to quit the game and load it a 2nd time, a 3rd time, etc, then disk swapping becomes very slow, disk can't keep up with the CPU demands, and the game can't finish loading (or it does finish loading taking 7 times the normal time) Now this is the surprising part: if I Logout of my desktop and Login once again, the game loads fast once again, like if I had rebooted my computer. SOMETHING is interfering with Disk I/O, but I'm not sure what exactly.

Comment: Looks like "Cities Skylines" is a C# app ([implied here](https://skylines.paradoxwikis.com/Modding_API)).  I guess it's running under mono. The [mono garbage collector](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/garbage-collector/sgen/) may have similarities to java and cause the same kind of "panic". Very curious that logging out helps.  Have you checked if `mono` is still in your `ps -ef` list after quitting the game? I just wonder if logging out is quitting something in the background.